# button hovering not working in android

Tags: android, button, hover

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/name" /> -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:text="Login" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have a button, I want when I "hover" over the button it shows a hello message with a toast.

I have a button in the layout. I tried to fetch it by `findViewById` in the `FirstActivity`. Then I tried using `button.setOnHoverListener` but it isn't working.

```
package com.example.datapass;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);

        final EditText name ; 
        Button loginButton ;

        //final Context context = this;


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        //name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname) ;
        final TextView tv = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.textView1) );
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        loginButton.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("hover", "Bring yor cursor over the button");
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER)
                {
                    //tv.setText("hi");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Can you also please paste your layout file, 'form'? Thanks.

Comment: sure.I just pasted my layout file , named form.xml

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth changing your `onHover` method to be like below and break once it carries out an individual action:

```
@Override
public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would also advise changing this line as this is not standard format/syntax:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.textView1) );
```

To be this instead:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

However I think your actual issue is more relating to the support on mobile devices of hovering as none of your code actually seems like it would break this code section. The majority of devices can only recognise hovers whilst using a stylus and not actually just with a finger. Only some of the higher end devices can actually recognise a hover action with just a finger. This might be something to note and may be advisable to use a swipe or a click instead of a hover to display the `Toast`.

Comment: Thank you so much Edwoollard for the corrections, But its not working though, Can you give any suggestions about how without clicking the work can be done